# match query on two collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections, one is employee and other is salary and we have an employee id as a reference from salary to employee collection . I want a query, which can give all employee  whose salary exists in salary collection  with salary details and the employee whose salary doesn't exist will return zero salary.

In simple, I need right outer join in mongodb.
please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "show me the code" .... show the query first which you tried.

Comment: I first did find query on employee then find query on salary then iterate using for loop

Comment: in this case result is coming but I thing this is not good solutions

Answer (score 1):

```
//Employee Documents
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c41aaa91d0b034e617effc0"),
    "emp_id" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c41aaec1d0b034e617f0001"),
    "emp_id" : 2
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c41aaf31d0b034e617f0009"),
    "emp_id" : 3
}

//Salary Documents:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c41aac01d0b034e617effd4"),
    "emp_id" : 1,
    "salary" : 1000
}
**//Query**
db.employee.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "salary",
            localField: "emp_id", //reference of employee collection
            foreignField: "emp_id",  //reference of salary collection
            as: "sal"
         }
    },{
       $unwind: {
             path: "$sal",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true //will return null if salary does not exist
        }
      },{
         $project:{
             emp_id: 1,
             salary:  { $ifNull: [ "$sal.salary", 0 ] } //will set to 0 if salary does not exist
             }  
       }]);

//Output
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c41aaa91d0b034e617effc0"),
    "emp_id" : 1,
    "salary" : 1000
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c41aaec1d0b034e617f0001"),
    "emp_id" : 2,
    "salary" : 0.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c41aaf31d0b034e617f0009"),
    "emp_id" : 3,
    "salary" : 0.0
}
```

Comment: @mks try the above code, i have created the sample documents of employee and salary, you can find them in the top of the solution posted based on which i tried the query which you are expecting

Comment: Thanks for your reply. since employee collection is not referring to salary but salary referring to employee. so in this case  "Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators" error is coming

Comment: below is the salary schema

var Salary=mongoose.Schema({
   employee_id:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employees' }]

Comment: Please the share the sample schema of both employee and salary

Comment: salary schema I shared you already which refers to _id of employee table. and Employee schema is

var Employee=mongoose.Schema({
    first_name:String,
    middle_name:String,
    last_name:String,
    employee_id:String"